# show div with javascript without an ID

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a php file that is "included" multiple times so nothing on there has an ID, however only one is ever visible at one time. I am wanting to make a div visible within this PHP depending one what is typed, can I do this even though it doesn't have an ID? included php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mobilecheck(inputted) {
        var findstring = "07";
        if (inputted.indexOf(findstring) > -1)   {   
            //this works, I have tested with an 'alert'
document.getElementsByName("hiddenMobileDiv").style.display="block"; 
//show hidden div - this bit isn't working, I think it's because there's multiple divs with this name
            }

    }
</script>

    <input type="tel" class="textbox" name="contactno" onkeypress="mobilecheck(this.value)">
    <div name="hiddenMobileDiv" style="display:none">
        <label class="label">What time can we contact you until?</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: When you say "only one is visible", does that mean that you are removing the other ones from the DOM - or only setting their display to none?  If they still exist on the DOM, there has to be additional criteria used to determine the correct one to display.  If they're removed, you can use joe_young's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName` returns an array, so you will need to use:

```
document.getElementsByName("hiddenMobileDiv")[0].style.display="block";
```

Adding an `[0]` to reference the first item in the array of elements with the name *'hiddenMobileDiv'*

---

Or, if you have more than one *'hiddenMobileDiv'* element or you want to show all of them, us a for loop:

```
for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByName("hiddenMobileDiv").length; i++)
    document.getElementsByName("hiddenMobileDiv")[i].style.display="block";
```

Comment: This will only work if the desired div appears first in the DOM.  It's possible that he has three divs all with this name, but the desired one to show appears third in the DOM.  If that's the case, your code will display the wrong div.